# Simple Sitecore ASP Repeater - Accessing Fields

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitecore

I have a pretty basic sitecore question here.  I want to iterate over a group of child objects (locations), and display some information about each.

I'm using an ASP repeater to do the iteration, I'm getting the children on the page load, and I'm trying to use the sc tags to display the information - but I'm not getting to show up on the page.

Can anyone help me out to see what I'm missing here?

Code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var item = Sitecore.Context.Item;

        var children = new List<Sitecore.Data.Items.Item>();
        foreach (var child in item.GetChildren())
        {
            children.Add((Sitecore.Data.Items.Item)child);
        }

        LocationsRpt.DataSource = children;
        LocationsRpt.DataBind();
    }
```

Markup:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="LocationsRpt" OnItemDataBound="LocationsRptItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="InnerContentSec clearfix">
            <div id="AboutSolar" class="AboutSolar clearfix">
                <div class="items">
                <h3>
                    <sc:Text runat="server" ID="Title"/>
                </h3>
                <div class="LocationBlock clearfix">
                <div class="ImgSec">
                    <sc:Image id="Image" runat="server" Width="185" Height="107" />
                </div>
                <div class="DescSec">
                    <p><sc:Text ID="ShortDescription" runat="server" /></p>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

And, finally on  DataItemBound

```
protected void LocationsRptItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            var subItem = e.Item.DataItem as Item;  

            if (subItem != null)
            {
                var appTitle = e.Item.FindControl("Title") as Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Text;

                if (appTitle != null)
                {
                    appTitle.DataSource = subItem.ID.ToString();
                    appTitle.Field = "Application Title";
                    appTitle.DataBind();
                }

                var appImage = e.Item.FindControl("Image") as Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Image;

                if (appImage != null)
                {
                    appImage.DataSource = subItem.ID.ToString();
                    appImage.Field = "Location Image";
                    appImage.DataBind();
                }

                var shortDescription = e.Item.FindControl("ShortDescription") as Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Text;

                if (shortDescription != null)
                {
                    shortDescription.DataSource = subItem.ID.ToString();
                    shortDescription.Field = "Short Description";
                    shortDescription.DataBind();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't see any code that actually uses fields from your collection. Are they in the LocationsRptItemDataBound event handler?

Comment: added my on item data bound event

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could also do it like so:

Pageload:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LocationsRpt.DataSource = Sitecore.Context.Item.GetChildren();
    LocationsRpt.DataBind();
}
```

Markup:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="LocationsRpt">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="InnerContentSec clearfix">
            <div id="AboutSolar" class="AboutSolar clearfix">
                <div class="items">
                <h3>
                    <sc:Text runat="server" ID="Title" Item="<%# Container.DataItem %>"/>
                </h3>
                <div class="LocationBlock clearfix">
                <div class="ImgSec">
                    <sc:Image id="Image" runat="server" Width="185" Height="107"  Item="<%# Container.DataItem %>" />
                </div>
                <div class="DescSec">
                    <p><sc:Text ID="ShortDescription" runat="server"  Item="<%# Container.DataItem %>" /></p>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

In this case you don't need the databound event.

Comment: You can also just set the repeater DataSource to
`<asp:Repeater runat="server" DataSource="<%# Sitecore.Context.Item.GetChildren() %>" >` if you want to get rid of the CodeBehind :)

Comment: I went with this answer eventually.  Thanks all for the help!

Comment: I had a issue where one of the fields was a multiList field and the GUIDS were showong up.  I had to create an OnItemDataBound method on the repeater, go to sitecore for each item, then build a string of text and pass on.

Comment: Yes, that's expected. Some complex fields (multilistfields, droplinks etc) just contain GUIDs, and the above code just outputs what the field contains. You as a dev have to build something to tell Sitecore what to do with that GUID (as you've done in the OnItemDataBound)

Comment: I'd also recommend to remove the whole Databound event override, and put the Field definitions in the aspx/ascx code, e.g. `<sc:Text runat="server" ID="Title" Field="Application Title" Item="<%# Container.DataItem %>"/>`

Answer (score 2):

I was too fast, you added your eventhandler code after I replied.

In your eventhandler you should set the `Item` property for the field controls.
So for example: `appTitle.Item = item`

And you don't need to call DataBind() for those controls.

Also, you can just use `item.GetChildren()` as datasource for the repeater, you don't have to copy the children to a new list.