# Iterating over Sitecore Placeholder

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitecore

I've been trying to iterate over a placeholder in sitecore.  Essentially, there control that needs to be repeated by the page for a collection of elements (say a tab).  I've only gotten the placeholder to render once.  The following tabs don't have content inserted into them.

The code for something like what I'm trying to do is:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptTabs" runat="server">
    <sc:Placeholder ID="plSocialSharing" runat="server" Key="Social"/>
    <sc:Placeholder ID="plTab" runat="server" Key="content"/>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Should something like what I'm doing work?  If it doesn't, do I need to user another sitecore control (something more dynamic?).  Should I instead be using user controls I place there, or should I stick with the sitecore framework approach?

Comment: What type of thing would your placeholders contain, within each tab? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Well, social sharing tools would be something like facebook sharing, email buttons.  Each tab would contain some markup containing pictures/images pulled from sitecore.  I'm trying to keep the question generic.  Say, the current item you are on in sitecore has a list of gallery pages.  Each gallery page contains text and images that need to be displayed.  I'm trying to iterate over the plTab placeholder and render each tab object that I pull from the current sitecore object.

Comment: Will each tab need a different different sublayout/rendering or will they all use the same one?

Comment: Same one.  It looks like I might need to use the sitecore dynamic place holder control?

Comment: No, that's for using the same placeholder keys more than once in the same page - assuming you are talking about this: http://trueclarity.wordpress.com/2012/06/19/dynamic-placeholder-keys-in-sitecore/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since each of your tabs will contain the same rendering the I would not bother with placeholders. I think you will be adding more complexity than is required.

Assuming you are going to be using the [jQuery UI Tab plugin](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/) then I would use the same technique you used in the [previous question you asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16566680/simple-sitecore-asp-repeater-accessing-fields), i.e. render out the content of the div tabs in the repeater, and you will need another repeater to create the `ul` list of the actual tabs.

Assuming you have a tree structure like:

```
- Social Sharing
-- Facebook
-- Twitter
-- Email
```

You could now `Social Sharing` use as the datasource of your `Repeater` and still allow the content of the tabs to be editable if you use Sitecore controls.

If you wanted something much more dynamic, like different rendering for each of the tabs, for example one with rich text, one with 2 column, one with table etc, then again there are a couple of ways of achieving this. One way would be to use standard `<asp:PlaceHolder>` in your repeater and add the rendering in this from your codebehind on ItemDataBound event.

Another option would be to add a bunch of different renderings into the placeholder in the page editor and set the datasource of each to content item. It will be difficult to use jQueryUI Tabs with this though since you would want markup like this in each control to make them self contained:

```
<div class="tab-title">Tab Title</div>
<div class="tab-content">Put whatever content you want in here</div>
```

As long as each rendering followed this structure then it would be easy to add several of these to the page and they would still be editable in the Page Editor, albeit listed one after another (not in tab format) in Editing mode. You would need to roll your own tab plugin, but it could be something as simple as:

- Only in Preview or Normal mode

  1. Get all `.tab-title` elements
  2. Create a `ul` list and prepend to the tab container
  3. Now call jQuery UI Tabs on the element

Hopefully given you some options at least, I can expand on any of these if it something you need but will have to get some code samples together.